# Nodemon is not recognized as an internal command operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nodemon

I was working with NodeJS, but due to some other issue I installed Windows again. Now I have installed nodemon gloabally and it also show version in C drive, but when I try to run project it gives me the error:

> nodemon is not recognized as an internal command operable program or batch file

Comment: Make sure `nodemon` is on your path. How did you install `nodemon "gloabally"? What do you mean "it also show version in C drive"? What do you mean "try to run project"?

Comment: globally mean 
npm install -g nodemon 
c drive mean when i access user in commond prompt i shows the version mean its install but when i try to run project from E drive it shows the error

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand what you mean "when I access user in command prmopt i shows the version mean its installed". Please write simple, declarative English sentences, separated by periods.

Comment: Or show the specific, actual commands you are using and the specific, actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was Loading error and was completely loaded after i restart System so that works

Answer (score 6):

1. Run: `$ npm install -g nodemon`
2. Run: `$ npm install --save-dev nodemon`
3. Change **package.json** file as:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

4. Run: `$ npm run serve`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have nodemon dependency in **package.json** file in your current project. If you don't see it listed in this file run `npm i nodemon --save`

Once checked, you might execute nodemon by:

- running script `nodemon index.js` (or whatever name your js file has)
- running command `npm run start` (though you have to update scripts in your package.json file with new script `"start": "nodemon index.js"`)
- running command `nodemon`, but in this case you have to have index.js file in your  current project as well, as by default nodemon will try to find and execute index.js file.

Answer (score 2):

I installed it as "npm install -g nodemon".
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In My Windows this is Work :

1. npm install -g nodemon
2. Open your folder that you want to run nodemon, ex in my picture:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUTnV.jpg
3. in Terminal write : Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
4. in Terminal write : nodemon

Answer (score 0):

You write install instead of init
Run npm install nodemon

Answer (score -3):

1. first try this: npm install -g nodemon if this not work in case of mine
2. try yarn add nodemon it will work